# how to draw an image on a canvas with transparency/alpha

Tags: c#, gdi+

hy there!

i left out usings etc... just plain code:

```
var image = Image.FromFile(/* my magic source */);
var bitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
var brush = new SolidBrush(/* my magic color */);
canvas.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
canvas.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height));
canvas.Save();
bitmap.Save(/* my magic target */);
```

i want to draw `image` with alpha 55% on `canvas`. `image` is a .png-file and uses transparency itself. (NOTE: i do not want to make `image.MakeTransparent()` - it is already transparent, i just need some alpha-effect)

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try ColorMatrix and ImageAttributes:

```
ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
cm.Matrix33 = 0.55f;
ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
ia.SetColorMatrix(cm);
canvas.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
```

Comment: your overload of `DrawImage` does not exist: i've used: `canvas.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);`

Comment: This way seem only working for Rgb24 Pixel Format. I tried Argb32 or Indexed8bpp, Its not work.